# Project got disconected from remote git, how to reattach?

Tags: eclipse, egit

I'm facing an unexpected problem that is messing with my daily agenda, and I'm already tight with time. The project I'm working got detached from remote git repository. I'm not sure how did this happened, could be that I have mistakenly deleted while on Git Repository Exploring in Eclipse.

Anyways, I have things to push, so I need somehow to reattach the project to the remote repository without losing local changes (and getting back all the git goodies like revision, branches etc).

I would like to avoid pulling again from the Git, and than do compare with my current work to get the changes, so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at your remotes list in eclipse, probably the remote was deleted and you just need to add it again. Once you add it, you will get your remote branches back. After you add your remote eclipse will do a fetch for you, so you don´t need to pull.

Comment: Hi thanks, Aag. I think that that was it but can't confirm as I have, due to time-pressure, checked-out the complete project again and did a local diff. However, before that I did do fetch and added the uri of my remote repo. The remotes list appeared, just as you're suggesting, but I was still not getting the push option enabled. Seems that the complete solution to the problem was to do what you're suggesting, and than select a remote from list and choose a configure for push option, but as said can't confirm now as I fixed it sort of manually.

Comment: Unfortunately I´m not using eclipse so much these days so I´m not sure why the push button was not clickable. It might be you need to mark your local branch as a tracking branch of your remote new somehow ( just a guess)